# JGroups not forming cluster between two linux machines (Red Hat 7)

Tags: jgroups

I tried to use in JGroups-3.6.6 library to manage the communication between 2 hosts in the cluster.
it is working fine for me on Windows cluster, but not on Linux (Red Hat 7 in this case).
any idea what could be the reason, and how can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What protocol you are using ? .. if you are using UDP probably it is blocked in your network which is the case in most organisations.Try switching to TCP and you can give initial hosts for testing purposes.

Comment: I'm using in TCP, and initial hosts are configured correctly.

Comment: assuming that you have verified the connectivity between two systems ..Instead of using TCPPING switch to another protocol for membership discovery for eg FILE_PING and give a location shared by both the systems if possible or try JDBC_PING